# How to view the median and IQR of complex data sets

Tags: r

Now, I have a dataframe “df”.I now want to elegantly get the median and IQR of values in R when S == "a" and G == "A". Not only that, I also want to get the median and IQR of the values in R when S and G are other values. I want to know a convenient and elegant method. Please help me

```
df<-data.frame(
      S = c("a","a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","b","b","a","a"),
      R = c("10","15","20","30","30","30","30","30","30","30","15","20"),
      G = c("A","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the `.by` argument provided within the summary function. This works like `group_by`. Notice that your `R` is not numeric, we therefore coerce it to numeric before doing any calculations. `IQR` function automatically does this.

```
df %>%
   summarise(med = median(as.numeric(R)), iqr = IQR(R), .by = c(S,G))

  S G med   iqr
1 a A  15  5.00
2 a B  25 11.25
3 b B  30  0.00
4 b A  30  0.00
```

---

```
df %>%
   group_by(S, G) %>%
   summarise(med = median(as.numeric(R)), iqr = IQR(R))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   S [2]
  S     G       med   iqr
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     A        15   5  
2 a     B        25  11.2
3 b     A        30   0  
4 b     B        30   0
```